# How to implement appsecret_proof in jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have already running Facebook login and then Faceook strikes with security questions and asked us to enable `require app secret` and until they limited our app and we were not able to login. Now we enabled the app secret but upon login they are sending an error message

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "APM.........."
   }
}
```

I am sending this API to grant for the permission

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name,gender', function(response) {
```

How do I send the appsecret_proof here in jquery? Also let me know that if I am only using login facility, so I need to enable the require app secret?

Comment: The app secret - clue in the name there - must never be exposed in publicly available code. And calculating the proof needs that secret ... so doing this on the client side is simply a big NO to begin with. The documentation also explicitly says that this is for server-side API calls only. _"I am sending this API to grant for the permission"_ - that is not requesting any permissions, it is requesting the user details.

Comment: I can't tell why they would think a request made using the JS SDK's `FB.api` was server-side to begin with. But the app-secret proof thing should not be relevant here, if using the JS SDK is all you are doing, and there are no server-side API calls involved.